# Can Nashorn viably port JavaScript libraries to the JVM side of cross-built Scala.js projects?

Tags: javascript, java, scala, scala.js, nashorn

This question addresses the flip side of another question: [Can JSweet viably port Java libraries for use in cross-built Scala.js projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51033981/can-jsweet-viably-port-java-libraries-for-use-in-cross-built-scala-js-projects)

Imagine making a Scala.js facade for a JavaScript library, then compiling the JavaScript library to the JVM.  Then, by wrapping the JVM version in a way that conforms to the same interface as the Scala.js facade,the result would be a Scala.js Cross-Built library that could serve the JS and JVM communities, as well as the Scala.js community.

Have you ever used Rhino or Nashorn to make a JavaScript library available to Java or Scala?

How did you do it?

If you haven't done it, do you have any ideas about whether, or how it could be done?

Comment: Yes. Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32251807/how-do-you-invoke-a-method-in-a-nashorn-compiledscript). It's trivial.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch that might be a good first step.